# Python Exception Handle a Lib

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been playing around with this but I can't quite seem to figure out the syntax. I'm trying to exception handle a specific exception thrown from an Amazon API lib.

It throws the exception:

> class 'amazon.api.AsinNotFound'

I've tried:

```
except AsinNotFound
```

and

```
except amazon.api.AsinNotFound
```

I can handle it with just an except but I want to be able to catch this specific case if possible. If it's not I could look for the text in `sys.exc_info()` but that doesn't seem like a neat way of doing it.

Example:

```
try:
  DoSomethingWithASIN
except amazon.api.AsinNotFound:
  print "No ASIN"
except:
  print "this part triggers instead"
```

Comment: `except amazon.api.AsinNotFound:` should work fine once you put it in the correct place.

Comment: My IDE shows local variable amazon might be referenced before assignment. The 'except amazon.api.AsinNotFound:' doesn't trigger and just the except: does.

Comment: Add how you are using it as something does not sound right.

Comment: Added a snippet. Thanks for taking a look I'm a little stumped with how this is supposed to work.